How to handle iOS status bar color when drawer is opened?
In Android, it handles the status bar color when the drawer is opened and closed.


You can see Android handle this properly.
In iOS it not showing properly.


Please help me to solve this issue. Thankyou:)
I have tried to find this solution by using these two lines also.
<key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key> 
<false/>

<key>UIStatusBarHidden</key>               
<true/>  

AnnotatedRegion(
      value: const SystemUiOverlayStyle(
        statusBarIconBrightness: Brightness.dark,
        statusBarColor: Colors.transparent,
)

But I didn't get the Result.

Try exploring AnnotatedRegion

Try this:
appBar: AppBar(
      systemOverlayStyle: SystemUiOverlayStyle.dark
    ),

Or you can set it in main function:
void main() {
  SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle.dark);
  runApp(const App());
}


But it darkens the entire app's status bar, and I want only the specific drawer's app bar to be dark.
appBar: AppBar(
systemOverlayStyle: SystemUiOverlayStyle.dark
),
i have tried also this.

@SalmanNaghori Are you using ListView inside drawer?

Yes i am using listview

Then try to give padding: EdgeInsets.zero inside ListView.
